Can gigantic boulders resemble mountains given a long enough time?
As a human mage, Mountain Slinger is infamous for one spell: creating boulders thousands of meters big, putting it in a gigantic sling-like mana structure, and hurling it at her target after building enough kinetic energy. Usually, she'd float a few kilometers to the air before flinging. For personal reasons, she prefers her boulders to not shatter on impact so the rocks of the boulders are chosen with that in mind. Her usual targets are entire cities and armies.
It is commonly said among the common folk that the thrown boulders would eventually transform into mountains thus she was given her title.
I intend for my world to be set millions of years into the future long after she's dead and magic disappears but the aftermaths of her spell still remain. For worldbuilding reasons, I need some of her thrown boulders to just look like mountains, enough to mislead the unaware(such as ancient tribes and medieval peasants) for a while up until the development of coherent mountain formation theories. The world is set on an alternate Earth.
My question is: Given millions of years, could some of the giant boulders eventually resemble mountains? If not, what would I need for it to be so?

A goddess(?) big enough to throw boulders that after millions of years of erosion are big enough to be mistaken for mountains and anyone/anything big enough to need a mountain-sized rock to be thrown at it seem a bit big to be on a standard Earth-like world, so where were they thrown from and to?  The energy involved will matter a lot.

This question has quite a few variables that the answer would depend on. Firstly, rock =/= rock. If a mountains composition doesn't match the surrounding area at all, any geologist worth their salt would spot it in two seconds flat. Secondly, how far are these boulders thrown? A massive crater around impact zone would be pretty noticeable.  Thirdly, are the boulders fragile and easily corrodible and break on impact, or made of strong rock that endure flinging and the test of time?

There is a word for isolated mountains rising in splendid solitude: inselberg. They are less common than mountain chains, but nevertheless they occur on all continents. Probably the most iconic is Uluru in Australia.

A boulder the size of the mountain, I call a mountain. If Mountain-Slinger launches mountains with a sling, they will not roll like marbles after landing; they will crash, i. e. convert to km-high piles of rubble. After millions of winters and some hundreds of earthquakes, they should have turned to piles of sand and be spread quite thin over all the continents.

It might be better to reduce the time. Erosion reduces mountains significantly. Volcanoes generally disappear after a few million years. The Appalachians were as high as Everest 65 million years ago. Yosemite Valley has a lot of "mass wasting" events every year. Drainage basins erode up to 537 meters per million years with glaciers speeding that up. https://rock.geosociety.org/net/gsatoday/archive/21/8/article/i1052-5173-21-8-4.htm

Boulder thousand meters long from height of  thousand meters? Gravitational potential energies calculations would show this is easily getting to nuclear weapon level energies. Eg a cube of granite 1000m a side with center of mass dropped from 1000m height would have energy in range of 1e16J or 2Mt tnt equivalent.  Targets will look more like impact craters or nuclear detonation sites. Launched boulders will be vaporized for the most part.   Height of drop should be dialed down to closer to ten meters If keeping to standard physics rules.

I am assuming the created boulder is homogenous makeup, worse if it is a conglomerate makeup. A boulder that large would probably begin to fracture and break up as it is accelerated to be thrown, and on impact would further break apart.
Again depending on the boulders makeup speed and trajectory on impact, in the beginning, it might appear as a large but broad hill of very disparate sized boulders. From there erosion will smooth out sharp edges, and further flatten the hill and boulder field. Depending again on how many millions of years are involved.
I do not think it would end up as a monolithic structure like Uluru in Australia. 
After millions of years it would appear to be a large collection of boulders that do not match the local geology, accumulated sediment filling in the low places and gaps.

